# Swing Timer Tick erratic, not regular

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

I am rather new to Java but not programming in general.  I am using Java 1.7.0_07 on Windows Vista.  I am trying to figure out how to make the Swing `Timer` tick at regular intervals.

I've noticed that even though I set the timer delay, and have nothing in my `actionPerformed` event handler but a `repaint()` method, the timer ticks are not steady or even accurate.

I have been searching for a solution for some time now, and have looked at, Dr John B Matthews rather neat [Kinetic Model example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel).  In his example, the default delay is 40mS, but the timer actually ticks at 47mS +/- 1mS (with an occasional variance from 32mS to 63mS).  The time spent inside his `actionPerformed` event handler is always 0mS.  These results are derived from running his code as an application.

If you closely watch the 'atoms' move, the stuttering is noticeable.  I don't understand what is causing the timer to behave this way.
I have the minimum windows tasks on my computer running but the problem is still present.

Is there a solution to this issue or is this just a feature of Java?

Comment: *"Kinetic Model example"*  Was it running as an applet or application when you saw the behavior described?  I would tend to test in an app.  And yes, I think that inaccuracy is a feature of `Timer`.

Comment: Andrew, thnx for having a look.  I ran it as an app.  (Editted my post to reflect that aspect.)

Answer (score 2):

I did not look at the source code or did a thorough investigation. But my best guess is that this is "a feature".

The `javax.swing.Timer` guarantees you that the `actionPerformed` method is called on the EDT. So whenever the `Timer` reaches its interval, it will probably schedule a `Runnable` on the EDT which in turn will call the `actionPerformed` method. However, if the EDT is busy at that exact moment (e.g. doing a repaint), it cannot execute that `Runnable`.

So a small delay is inevitable ...

Just checked the source code and seems my initial guess is correct

```
void post() {
     if (notify.compareAndSet(false, true) || !coalesce) {
         AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
             public Void run() {
                 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doPostEvent);
                 return null;
            }
        }, getAccessControlContext());
    }
}
```

It uses an `invokeLater` to schedule the `Runnable` (most likely so that you do not cumulate  delays as would be the case with an `invokeAndWait`). But that means that between the moment the timer posts the event and the `actionPerformed` method is actually triggered, the EDT must finish his previous tasks. And since there is no mechanism to say: "hey EDT, stop what you are doing right now and perform my work first", there is no mechanism to avoid the delay.

Perhaps you might get better results by writing your own `Timer` which uses the `SecondaryLoop` (available in JDK7). But that is a wild guess (I tried nothing)

Comment: I understand your general description of the problem, though I don't understand the code sample you gave.  The Kinetic Model code uses 'invokeLater' but only to kick off the whole application.  The Timer is setup later on.

Comment: The time in the actionPerformed method is 0mS, so it is quick enough.  In my own code, which has the timer set to fire at 2000mS intervals, my data indicates the timer actually fires at around 2014mS (+/-5mS).  My code does nothing but repaint a JFrame with an empty JPanel in it.  14mS from 2000mS, not to mention the variation is a huge time lag when considering my CPU is running at 2.5GHz.

Comment: I had a look at the SecondaryLoop function, but am doubtful I can make it work for me as it relies on an event being generated (like a button press).  Also, it block the current thread while it executes the loop.  Maybe you can explain a little more (that what the API Docs are telling me).

Comment: The context of my endevour to get a fairly precise and regular timer tick is based on creating a game loop that doesn't jitter.  I'm not sure how others have been able to achieve it, but I can't seem to figure it out. (This issue reminds me of Microsoft's undocumented behavours that needed trial and error to sort out.  Except that in this case, I'm at a loss as to what I can do to make the timer behave as per the API documentation).

Comment: @user1756090 That code snippet is the part of the source code of the `Timer` class that schedules the trigger of the `ActionListener`. So it is not a code sample as in "a solution for your problem". The problem is not how quick your `actionPerformed` method is. The problem is that scheduling something on the EDT does not invoke it immediately as the EDT can be busy

Comment: @user1756090 Timer is not guaranteed to trigger precisely on time, only on or after the delay. The Event Dispatching Thread contains a queue of tasks that the EDT must process, this includes internal events as wells as OS events. The actionPerformed event is pushed onto the end of this queue when timer fires, this means even if the timer fires precisely on time, there is going to be a short delay before the actionPerformed method is called. Repaint suffers from the simular constraints. A call to repaint is a request to the repaint manager to schedule a paint at some time in the future